# Can supply and demand curves be used in electricity modelling?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand

Can the (Supply and Demand) curves be implemented in electricity modelling for a country ? How can this be modelled and how can the user set the interaction point between supply and demand?

Comment: It's rather hard to work out what it is you're asking. The short but useless answers to your questions are (1) yes, (2) lots of ways, (3) it's where the curves cross. To give you a useful answer will require the question to be a lot clearer, and maybe more specific. What is the market you are trying to model? Over what timescales? What's your research question?